# Remove docker images not recently used

Tags: docker

I've searched through docs about `docker prune` with many examples, but none were what I need.

How to delete docker images that weren't used since x (for example, 72 hours)?

I don't see a profit from nightly removing images, most of which will be pulled within next 12 hours.
But if something wasn't used for longer, it's likely no longer needed...

Comment: Docker doesn't track when the image was last used, but the image metadata usually includes when the image was built. Would a cleanup policy based on the image creation timestamp be useful?

Comment: @BMitch iNot much. An image might be built for a year, but used daily... On the other hand, the our images that we produce weekly are out-of-date after 2-3 weeks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this specific request isn't a built in feature in docker. You can run:

```
docker image prune -a --until=72h
```

which would delete all images created at least 72 hours ago, but that wouldn't take into account images that were created months ago and used today. Implementing what you're looking for would require a tool that monitors the `docker events` feed and maintains a separate database of images used recently.

Comment: Or it would require docker to write the last-access timestamp whenever the image is used (by docker run, pull, push or whatever). But 'is not implemented (now) ' is also an answer, even if I'd wish something eles.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo I suspect the reason they don't already write something like that to the image is to avoid mixing mutable data with what should be an immutable image. They'd need to track it separate from the image itself..

Answer (score 0):

Solving a very related problem, I want to smartly prune containers and associated objects from a CI/CD runner:

1. Stopped containers which haven't been run in 8 hours, and
2. Images that haven't had a container created from then in the last 72 hours,
3. and remaining dangling objects, ie, volumes, networks.

My algorithm is as follows:

```
Create a set of the IDs of all stopped/dead containers
For each Container in that set, 
     Get the Image (ID) associated with that Container
     Find its most recent "die" event-time less than the past 72 hours 
     If no die-event in past 72 hours:
        Add Image to Image-Purge-Set
        Add Container to Container-Purge-Set
     Else-If  no die-event in the past 8 hours:
        Add Image to Image-Keep-Set
     Else-If  die-event in the past 8 hours:
        Add Container to Container-Keep-Set
 
Subtract from each Purge-Set the Keep-Set

Remove all containers from the Container-Purge-Set
Remove all images from the Image-Purge-Set
Prune volumes, networks
```

Implementation using shell script, docker commands to follow.